# Event delegation -- list items with children of their own

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a list (ul) of items (li)s. I want to use event delegation to bind a click event to the list instead of to each individual item. I used the code below do to so successfully.

```
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName === 'LI') {
        doTheWork();
    }
});
```

Great. However, my list items are parents of other nodes, and when I click on those nodes, I never can call doTheWork because the target is not an li.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </li>
    <li>...
</ul>
```

How can I handle a click on a list item that has children without binding an event to each item itself? For example, if my list item has a title, how can I catch the click event on the list item when the user technically clicked on the title tag?

Comment: When you say your list items, is than `<li>`s?

Comment: I suggest `e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'li'` to make it work in XHTML too.

Comment: You must check all parents of the event target!

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `none`:

> The element is never the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) of mouse events; however, mouse events
>   may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value.

```css
#list > li * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
    console.log(e.target);
  }
});
```

```css
#list > li * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works very well! Do you know a way to make that work for IE < 11?